# Get only specific rows in MVC based on a column value

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following code to get data in MVC and show in the page:

```
@Html.Grid(Model).Named("profilesGrid").AutoGenerateColumns().Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Add(d => d.ProcessingStatus).Titled("Processing Status").Sortable(true).Filterable(true);;
    columns.Add(d => d.CheckListDate).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}").Sortable(true).Filterable(true);
}).WithPaging(20).Sortable().Filterable().WithMultipleFilters()
```

I want to only show data where the ProcessingStatus= "OrderCompleted"

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Then filter the data before you send it to the view

Comment: I have two tabs on the page, one where I show all the data, and another where i only want to show the "OrderCompleted" ones. If I filter the data before, i would have to create two models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `Model.Where(m => m.ProcessingStatus == "OrderCompleted")` the data you need? You could always do that inline right there in the `Html.Grid()`.

If you always want to filter to just those rows and don't need the other rows for anything else on the page, it would make more sense to filter it in your controller, view model, etc. before sending it to the view.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly what i was looking for. Did i mention that I am a noob to this razor MVC? :)